# How does one get the results of 'exec' to show in the invoking shell?

Tags: tcl

I'm using a tcl gui only to assist in creating valid command lines which are otherwise too irritating to type. I simply want what is executed to appear in the shell in which I launch the gui, and all results as well, exactly as though I typed in the command (which below, is only 'ls -l').

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

wm title . "Console wishing thingy"
wm minsize . 400 400
# -------------------------------------------------------------

set buttonFrame   [labelframe .button_frame   -borderwidth 1 -text "Buttons to Click"]

set quit_button   [button $buttonFrame.quit_button -text "Quit" -command "exit"]
set run_it_button [button $buttonFrame.run_it_button -text "execute ls -l" -command {do_run}]
pack $buttonFrame.quit_button   -side left
pack $buttonFrame.run_it_button -side right

grid $buttonFrame   -sticky w -pady 5

proc do_run {} {
        exec ls -l
}
```

No results. No errors. But, no console output either.

Comment: Try typing `echo $?` it will show you the return value of the last command run.

Comment: You mean from the shell? I need to have the gui launch a command, a simulation, exactly as it would have been invoked had I typed the command in the shell. I don't need a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I simply want what is executed to appear in the shell in which I launch the gui, and all results as well

It depends, you have several options:

(1) `proc do_run {} { exec 1>@stdout 2>@stderr ls -la }`

With these directives, the Tcl process running `exec` will show the executed command's stdout and stderr as it were its own.

(2) `proc do_run {} { puts [exec ls -la] }`

Without directives, as above, `exec` returns the captured stdout of the executed command. Using `puts` will print the returned stdout to the Tcl process' stdout. stderr will cause `exec` to return a Tcl error, which will be handled in the wish, Tk way.

(3) `proc do_run {} { exec >&@stdout ls -la }`

If you don't want to handle stderr specifically, this will mold both into the Tcl process's stdout.

See also https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/exec.

Comment: Thanks. I think that #3 is what I want, but why it doesn't grok stdout I do not yet know: couldn't execute "&>@stdout": no such file or directory

Comment: Oh. ls is fine, it looks like I need to quote the "ls -l". Thanks again.

Comment: Sry, this way me introducing a glitch: option (3) is to write `>&@stdout`, not `&>@stdout`. No need for quoting or so.

Comment: mrcalvin thank you for that correction. It's perfect now and no quoting or escaping needed.